# Is SoapUI terminal server enabled?

Tags: soapui, citrix

I access parts of my client's intranet via citrix. I would like to add SoapUI to the applications that are available to me.

My client asks whether "SoapUI is terminal server enabled". I have no idea if that is the case. Does someone have an answer (perhaps with a clear reference) that I can cite?

Thank you very much for your insights!

Comment: Moritz, have you got chance to look at the answer? does that help?

Answer (score 1):

SoapUI is an open source  software tool that allows to test their API (both soap / rest), JDBC, HTTP requests. Apart from it, it allows to automate the API tests.

It acts a client software not server side.

It has UI where it can be used to their design tests and add assertions. It has also commandline utility testrunner.bat(.sh) under SOAPUI_HOME/bin directory which allows to execute the tests in headless mode.

Hope the above clarifies the question.

For more information, refer: https://www.soapui.org/open-source.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am not sure that it really answers my question - perhaps I did not pose it appropriately. I know soapUI and use it in my work. The problem is the following: after a fundamental change in my client's network I have access only via citrix, that is, every application has to be installed in a special area before I can use it. I would like soapUI to be installed there as well. My client wants to know if soapUI works with a terminal server. This specific question is my problem. I hope this makes it clearer. If not, then tell me please.

Comment: What do you mean by `soapUI works with a terminal server`? Install soapUI in your machine and access the application which might be deployed in your client network. Simple, In my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I think it *is* simple, too. But (as I am not a citrix expert) I am unsure how to answer my client's question to my original request. It would be great if I could find an explicit claim that soapUI is runnable via citrix. But perhaps such a claim cannot be found because either nobody cares to know or otherwise it's just trivial. +1 from me anyway for your time which is valuable.

Comment: See, like I mentioned, your computer is client which access your clients network using citix. SoapUI is just a software installed in your machine. It can invoke any service running as long as network is reachable. There is not anything specific to your client specially required by soapui. May be you can just show your client a small demo saying you can invoke the application services using soapui. Please updated once it done. Happy to assist if any.